# can I use open graph in my web app

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I want to parse information like title,images, etc from links posted,as facebook does, by reading og tags. Is this thing legal.... I mean will facebook have any objection if I do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ogp.me/

at the bottom of the page: 
The Open Graph protocol was originally created at Facebook and is inspired by Dublin Core, link-rel canonical, Microformats, and RDFa. The specification described on this page is available under the Open Web Foundation Agreement, Version 0.9. This website is Open Source. Last updated July 05th, 2012

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can can use Open Graph in your web app. And no, Facebook will not have any objection. It *is* called the *Open* Graph afterall.